# Clarification on analysis notes

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

[image]

[image]

Someone would be so kind as to explain to me how the highlighted part came about? Why is the function Min used instead of Max?

Comment: In limits, you really care about the behavior for $\epsilon$ small.  If you used max, then, when $\epsilon$ is small, $\delta$ would always be $1$, so $\max$ doesn't make as much sense.

Comment: What about the part highlighted in green?
$$\epsilon$$=$$\delta$$=3u
I can't figure out how $$\delta$$ = $$\epsilon$$/$$3$$

Comment: Please review how to format math text, your previous comment is hard to read (I don't know the proper link to send you to, so I'll let someone else make a suggestion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the trick:  In the string of inequalities, there is the line
$$
|u|^3+2|u|<|u|+2|u|.
$$
In other words, $|u|^3<|u|$.  This only happens when $0<|u|<1$.  Therefore, one condition that will need to hold is $|u|<1$.

Since you also want $|f(x)-7|<3|u|<\epsilon$, you also need $|u|<\epsilon/3$.

Recapping, you know that you need both $|u|<1$ and $|u|<\epsilon/3$ to hold.  So, you need $|u|$ to be smaller than the smallest of these two, which is the minimum of the two.

Comment: Perhaps you could also add why |u| is between 0 and 1? Is that an arbitrary choice?